# React icons size is HUGE

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-icons

I'm using React Icons in my website, and I've noticed that the package is quite large - almost 9MB In the network tab of developer tools (it's making the website taking much time to load on slow internet).
However, I'm only using a few icons at most.
Here's how I'm currently importing the icons in my code:

```
import { AiFillCloseCircle, AiOutlineMenu } from 'react-icons/ai';
```

I've tried searching for solutions online, but I couldn't find any clear answers on how to reduce the file size of React Icons when using only a few icons.

Can anyone suggest a solution or a best practice for using React Icons in a more efficient way? I'd like to reduce the size of my package as much as possible without compromising on functionality.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've tried lazy loading to at least show a loading spinner until it finishes the downloads
but thats doesn't work

Comment: Look at the following issue, it's an old thread but worth a try even thought it's 2.X https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons/issues/154

Answer (score -3):

how to  import
{ BsFillFileBarGraphFill }

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35058525)

Answer (score -5):

You should import them like this.

```
import FaFacebookSquare from 'react-icons/lib/fa/facebook-square';
import FaLinkedin from 'react-icons/lib/fa/linkedin';
import FaTwitter from 'react-icons/lib/fa/twitter';
import FaPinterest from 'react-icons/lib/fa/pinterest-square';
import FaInstagram from 'react-icons/lib/fa/instagram';
```

Comment: How does that differ

Comment: This doesn't appear to work anymore.